# Como passar uma requisição GET para um arquivo que não pertence ao wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, get

O wordpress não reconhece arquivos que não pertencem a ele, mesmo ele estando lá na pasta do tema, que é o meu caso. Com posso um fazer um arquivo externo receber essa informação?

Por exemplo: Eu estou em uma `.page` e lá existe um botão com um `parâmetro` via `GET`, através de um `link`. A page fica em:

```
www.meusite.com.br/tema/page.php
```

O arquivo alvo, que receberá o parâmetro é:

```
www.meusite.com.br/tema/src/arquivo.php
```

Esse `arquivo.php` somente foi colocado lá e não há nenhuma ligação com o wordpress, mas tem uma função de captura via **$_GET**.

> **DETALHE** :
>   Eu não quero acessar o arquivo através do front, ou seja, apresenta-lo no browse, mas somente faze-lo executar suas condições.

Comment: São arquivos `.php` que estão na pasta do tema, e você quer fazer algo como `arq.php?param=1`? É isso?

Comment: Você quer que esse .php use as funções disponibilizadas pelo WP? Ou esse .php tem código que não depende do WP?

Comment: Calo Felipe, são arquivos `.php` sim! E o parâmetro é tipo esse que você fez! P. R. Ribeiro esse .php depende do WP somente para global $wpdb.

Comment: Pessoal, o problema é somente esse! Não consigo obter um GET arq.php?param=1 DESSE arq.php (que faz parte do WP) para outro arq2.php, que está dentro do tema, mas não é "rodado" no front!

Comment: quando vc executa esse arquivo diretamente na url, ele funciona ou rola um `404`? (estou chutando o `404`)

Comment: Funciona para as páginas do wordpress, posts, etc...Mas para esse arquivo externo não.

Comment: Eu ACHO que isso ocorre por conta dos permalinks. Como você tenta acessar o arquivo diretamente, via `http://dominio.com.br/arq.php?param=1`, ele interpreta esse caminho como uma página, que na sua estrutura não existe. E o acesso direto a ele, via `wp_content/themes/tema/arq.php` é bloqueado. Acho que a solução é hospedá-lo ou fora do tema, ou criar ele como um template de página do wordpress mesmo...

Comment: @Lollipop, se ainda tem interesse nesta pergunta, pode editá-la para acrescentar detalhes? . . . . Os comentários não são a maneira de melhorar uma pergunta. Valeu!

Comment: @brasofilo, foi editada e ofereci uma recompensa para quem der a melhor resposta.

Comment: O que não entendo é o botão que fica em `page.php` e tem que rodar algo não relacionado com WP em `arquivo.php`... dá impressão que pode ser resolvido com uma requisição AJAX, mas sem saber a relação, difícil dizer se é isso mesmo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você esteja **sobreescrevendo os seus permalinks**, você não vai conseguir fazer isso mesmo, dado que o arquivo está dentro da **pasta do tema**. Isso ocorre por conta do fato do WordPress, quando com permalinks ativados, tratar as suas rotas através de `RewriteRule`s no `.htaccess`. Supondo que você vá no painel de administração e defina que suas URLs serão, por exemplo, baseadas no nome do post, o seguinte `.htaccess` é criado (retirei os exemplos de uma instância do WP que tenho rodando em `http://localhost/wp_testes/)`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp_testes/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp_testes/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866665/4682161), no SO gringo, da uma excelente explicação de como essas regras funcionam. Somando isso com a [Hierarquia de Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) do WP, é fácil de concluir que todas as requisições feitas dentro da sua instância do WP (no meu caso, de `/wp_testes/` pra frente), vão ser roteadas conforme essas regras, impedindo o acesso direto. Caso o seu arquivo `teste.php` não esteja de acordo com as regras de template, a casa vai cair.

## Soluções

1. Não utilize permalinks.

   É sujo, eu sei. Suas URLs vão ficar horríveis, mas isso vai permitir que você tenha acesso direto ao seu arquivo. No meu caso, desabilitei os permalinks, e fiz um acesso direto em `http://localhost/wp_testes/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/teste.php?teste=123`, onde `teste.php` continha essa instrução complicadíssima:

   ```
   <?php echo $_GET['teste']; ?>
   ```

   e o resultado, como esperado, foi

   > 123
2. Coloque o seu arquivo no **root** no WordPress

   Colocando o arquivo `teste.php` na pasta onde os arquivos do WP se encontram (no meu caso, dentro da pasta `/wp_testes`), as regras de permalink não devem afetar as suas requisições. Neste caso, fiz a requisição `http://localhost/wp_testes/teste.php?teste=123` (com permalinks ativados) e obtive o resultado esperado.

Não sei se você está desenvolvendo um necessariamente um tema, e se pode ou não incluir arquivos na raiz do WP. Acredito que você esteja limitado à essas duas soluções. Mas a soma das duas (permalinks com o arquivo *dentro* do tema), acho que não tem como.

Comment: Esse acho é o que mata sua resposta. Preciso de algo concreto. No geral, ta boa, mas incompleta nesse sentido. +1

Comment: Bom, eu poderia dizer que *tenho certeza* de que não tem como, hahaha. O acho foi mais construção de linguagem do que qualquer outra coisa, mas vale a dica pro futuro!

Comment: Caso ninguém der uma resposta melhor que a sua, que por sinal está ótima, tomarei como solução, pois a explicação do `.htaccess` foi boa.

Comment: Não esqueça de dar um +1 pro gringo que publicou a resposta que linkei lá no SO gringo. Aquela lá sim é de brilhar os olhos