# Index em Subpasta Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, cms

Estou montando um hotsite em `php` em subdiretório onde está o instalado o `WordPress`. Mas ao acessar a pasta está me dando o `error 404`, sendo que está com uma `index.php` normalmente. Pesquisei e não consegui localizar como resolver o problema. Gostaria somente de acessar a pasta normalmente `www.meudominio.com.br/hot-site-novo/`
Obrigado.

`.htaccess` atual.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: configurações > links permanentes "selecione a opção Nome do Post e clique em salvar" veja se resolve..

Comment: @PabloCampina já está nesta configuração. Obrigado!

Comment: por favor, de mais detalhes da sua configuração para que possamos entender o porque o problema está ocorrendo.

Comment: @PabloCampina estou com todas as configurações normais. Coloquei o `.htaccess` atual do WordPress. Quais informações podem ajudar?

Comment: deixa eu dar uma olhada no seu wp-config.php e ver a URL que está configurada na tabela wp_options coluna option_name opção siteurl

Comment: @PabloCampina está configurado o meu domínio local de teste. `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WPLANG', 'pt_BR');

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
 
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` Você quer acesso ao banco? Para verificar as tabelas?

Comment: Ao meu ver está tudo ok então, você outro wp rodando no mesmo servidor e está ok?

Comment: @PabloCampina O WordPress está funcionando normal, mas ele não está deixando acessar a subpasta que criei um novo arquivos index.php ao acessar está dando o 404. De alguma forma o WordPress está segurando o acesso desta index. Sendo que é um arquivo normal e simples.

Comment: @MoisesGama ele não vai deixar mesmo. Veja a resposta

Comment: @MoisesGama seu problema foi solucionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Remova qualquer regra do seu `.htaccess` que você conseguirá acessar `http://meudominio.com.br/hot-site-novo` sem problemas.

**Por que isso acontece?**

Perceba que o seu `WP` vive na raiz de `http://meudominio.com.br`. Em outras palavras, se você acessar os arquivos via o seu cliente FTP favorito, você vai encontrar os arquivos *default* do sistema, como a pasta `wp-content`, o arquivo `wp-config.php` e por aí vai.

Perceba também que você está usando regras de escrita (a.k.a. [permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)). Essas regras são maneiras de se criar *URLs* amigáveis para páginas, posts e afins dentro do WordPress mesmo que esse caminho não exista fisicamente.

Isso acontece porquê a rota `http://meudominio.com.br/hot-site-novo` é tratada pela aplicação e, dentro do escopo dela, a rota não existe.

**Como isso é feito?**

Através do `.htaccess`. Ele diz que, dado um acesso à raiz do site (i.e., `http://meudominio.com.br/alguma-coisa`, essa rota será tratada pela aplicação. Você pode alterar as suas regras de *permalink* (`configurações > links permanentes`) para qualquer coisa que não o "Padrão", e o `.htaccess` será sempre o mesmo. Faça o teste! O que ele faz, basicamente, é dizer que todo acesso a página vai passar pelo `index.php` (do WP) e, a partir de lá - e de acordo com as regras que você definiu - a aplicação vai saber o que te mostrar.

Com as regras de *permalink* definidas, não importa quantas outras pastas você coloque juntamente com os arquivos *default* do WP, e nem o que tenha dentro delas. *TODOS* os acessos vão ser roteados para o `index.php` do WP.

Caso você *remova* essas regras, o WP perde esse controle. Isso significa que a pasta `hot-site-novo` agora é "visível" para um acesso direto (novamente, faça o teste).

**E agora?**

É uma clássica situação de *trade-off*. Se você *realmente* quer fazer o seu `hot-site-novo` no pelo, e hospedá-lo juntamente com o WP (pelo teor da minha resposta você já deve notar que eu não sou muito adepto dessa prática), você vai ter que sacrificar as suas regras de escrita e, com elas, as *URLs* amigáveis. Isto significa que o seu WP vai responder a coisas como `http://meudominio.com.br/?page_id=39`. Se, por exemplo, você fez um *hardcode* no seu menu, e os links estão estáticos apontando para coisas como `http://meudominio.com.br/minha-pagina`, isso deixa de existir (já que a pasta `minha-pagina` não existe e nunca existiu), e BOOM! 404

Eu recomento fortemente que você modele o seu `hot-site-novo` dentro da lógica do WP. Fazer uma coisa do zero dentro desse ambiente não faz o menor sentido. A certo tempo, dei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953252/wordpress-template-object-not-found/31954248#31954248) no SO gringo sobre a hierarquia de templates do WP, e como usa-la corretamente. O teor da pergunta é diferente, mas o problema era basicamente o mesmo. [Essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66019/como-passar-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get-para-um-arquivo-que-n%C3%A3o-pertence-ao-wordpress/90154#90154), também minha, mas desta vez no SOpt, fala, também, sobre a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Este deveria ser apenas um comentário na resposta do Caio, mas não tenho reputação pra isso. O único adendo é que é possível alterar o .htaccess do wordpress para que ele não tenha efeito nas requisições feitas para aquela pasta. Acredito que alterando para algo como:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hot-site-novo.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

passe a funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive um outro problema. Coloquei o Wordpress em uma subpasta e ao ativar as URLs amigáveis deu error 403. O que fiz pra resolver foi deletar o .htaccess e adicionar o código abaixo no wp-config.php

add_filter('got_rewrite', '__return_false');

O código impede do Wordpress criar um novo arquivo .htaccess