# Permitir outro website em uma hospedagem com wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Eu tenho uma hospedagem com um wordpress na raiz.
Se eu criar uma pasta no ftp e upar outro site(não wordpress) nessa pasta quando eu requisito:

> www.site.com.br/pasta_nova_criada

O wordpress me devolve como "página não encontrada".Existe uma maneira de eu "permitir" que essa pasta seja vista e o wordpress não bloqueie?

Comment: Você tem alguma coisa dentro dessa `pasta_nova_criada`? Se você colocar um ficheiro normal `.html` ou uma imagem, etc e acessá-lo através do link direto (com a extenão) `www.site.com.br/pasta_nova_criada/ficheiro.html` tenho quase a certeza que poderá acessá-lo sem problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Index em Subpasta Wordpress](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100677/index-em-subpasta-wordpress)

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar um subdomínio? exemplo: http://suporte.site.com.br, a maioria dos hosts suportam a criação de subdomínios. Mas segue a orientação do @Chun.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tem uma forma que sei que vai dar certo de certeza, faça o seguinte: Coloque a instalação do wordpress em uma pasta também ex: www.site.com.br/site/ e o seu outro site da seguinte forma www.site.com.br/outrosite/ assim quando acessar www.site.com.br/ você cria um arquivo html redirecionando para www.site.com.br/site/ e quando acessar direto www.site.com.br/outrosite irá funcionar perfeitamente.