# Dúvidas sobre páginas e links no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro tema, sem ter nenhuma experiência anterior com o wordpress, tenho umas dúvidas...

Terei que ter várias páginas no meu tema, vi que posso separar em arquivos diferentes ("pag1.php", "pag2.php", etc...), como faço o apontamento para estas páginas no menu do site pelo admin do wordpress, para que fique com urls amigáveis (ex: http://www.meusite.com.br/pagina-01/), não encontrei nada do tipo no admin do WP, nem referências a páginas no functions.php ou em algum outro lugar.

Estas outras páginas também receberão parametros pela url, por exemplo: http://www.meusite.com.br/pagina-01/param-01/param-02/ mas isso ja vi basicamente como resolver...

Se perguntei na sessão errada me perdoem, confesso que não pesquisei muito aqui neste forum ainda.

Comment: Leia sobre [permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen). Já da pra você ter uma idéia sobre URLs amigáveis.  [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100677/index-em-subpasta-wordpress/100701#100701) eu dei uma resposta que fala sobre eles, talvez ela te ajude também.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOPT, de uma lida antes aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade são duas coisas diferentes. Existe a página que é onde você edita o conteúdo, define qual url vai usar e etc. e existe qual arquivo do seu tema o wordpress vai usar para exibir as informações da sua página.

O wordpress tem um caminho para descobrir qual é o melhor arquivo a ser usado, para entender melhor você pode ler [aqui](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), mas este [gráfico](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) talvez te dê uma ideia geral muito mais rapidamente.

Existe um jeito de atribuir um arquivo do seu tema à sua página que é usando o mesmo *slug*, ou seja, se o endereço da sua página é `/sobre` o wordpress vai tentar achar `page-sobre.php`, mas com isso você amarra as duas coisas e, se for necessário trocar o endereço da página, você pode acabar tendo problemas. O melhor é colocar no comecinho do seu arquivo algo como

```
<?php
/*
 * Template name: Nome do seu template
 */
```

E na tela de edição da sua página escolher o template que você criou. Espero que seja um bom começo pra você.