# Requisição ajax com Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou trabalhando em uma página personalizada Wordpress.
Estou fazendo uma requisição via ajax nesta página personalizada, que está diretório do tema:
wp-content/themes/meu-tema/minha-pagina-personalizada.php 
A página que vai processar também está no mesmo diretório, porém não funciona a requisição ajax, trazendo como retorno um erro 404. 
Acredito que devo fazer algum procedimento antes de apontar o caminho correto, talvez...
Segue meu código:

```
$(btMes).click(function(){
      // REQUISIÇÃO --- V I A --- A J A X
      var radioIn = $("input[name='radioVlrM']:checked").val();
      var dtIC = $("input[name='singleMonth']").val();        
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'processa.php',
            data: { 
                'radioC': radioIn,
                'dtiC': dtIC           
            },
            success: function(result){                
                var view = $('#result_media').html(result);
                $(table).show('slow');
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: De uma maneira bem resumida, o WP Não permite que você faça esses requests à arquivos pertencentes ao tema, pq isso não faz muito sentido. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66019/como-passar-uma-requisição-get-para-um-arquivo-que-não-pertence-ao-wordpress/90154#90154) que eu dei uma vez que fala exatamente desse problema.

Comment: O WordPress tem algumas particularidades de como lidar com requests Ajax, veja [Como fazer Ajax em WordPress do jeito certo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160069/5213)